# how does private cloud (saas provider) infrastructure different from internal infrastructure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, infrastructure

when we say private cloud, normally it refers to the internal infrastructure of the cloud provider. correct? I try to understand how does saas providers' private cloud infrastructure different from internal IT infrastructure in terms of the infrastructure and architecture design?

My understanding for saas provider Private cloud should be similar to internal IT infrastructure except the servers are purposely serve the customers so it need to have extremely high redundancy and scalability.

Comment: *"When we say private cloud, normally it refers to the internal infrastructure of the cloud provider. correct?"*  No, that isn't correct.  *Private Cloud* refers to infrastructure that a company deploys, internally, that provides features and capabilities that are similar to those of public cloud providers, but used only by business units within that single enterprise.  Private cloud does not refer to the private infrastructure of a public cloud provider.

Comment: Then what does the internal infrastructure called in a  SAAS provider?

Comment: SaaS is often hosted on IaaS/PaaS from another vendor, in which case the SaaS vendor infrastructure is entirely virtual.  I have techical/consulting/supporting relationships with several SaaS vendors and cannot recall encountering a specific term for the SaaS infrastructure as a whole other than discussion of *layers* or *tiers* (e.g. the database tier, app server tier, webhook tier, background jobs tier) and concepts like *control plane* (the components that handle deployment of new customer configuration, scaling, resharding, load redistribution, etc.).